# POST request getting 400 error code with pydev Eclipse but working on Postman

Tags: python, eclipse, api, request, postman

I am trying to call a post request which is working on Postman, but is returning 400 with my code. Here are my attempts:

```
url = "http://192.168.9.194:7780/xtv-ws-client/api/login/auth? 
accountid=342&password=3534"
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
rsp = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
print (rsp.status_code)
```

and

```
url = "http://192.168.9.194:7780/xtv-ws-client/api/login/auth"
Body1 = {
    "accountid": "342",
    "password": "3534"
}
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
rsp = requests.post(url, json=Body1, headers=headers)
print (rsp.status_code)
```

and

```
params = {'accountid': '342', 'password': '3534'}
url = "http://192.168.9.194:7780/xtv-ws-client/api/login/auth? 
accountid=342&password=3534"
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
rsp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, params = params)
print (rsp.status_code)
```

Here is my postman request:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
params = {'accountid': '342', 'password': '3534'}
url = "http://192.168.9.194:7780/xtv-ws-client/api/login/auth"
rsp = requests.post(url, data=params)
print (rsp.status_code)
```

Comment: @ColinMai please mark my answer as accepted then, by clicking the green checkmark below the voting buttons

Comment: yeah i have to wait 10 minutes